# SQL conversion without using JOIN keyword (Oracle jpa)

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to re-write the below without using the JOIN keyword? Like using the old method of joining tables.

```
SELECT Routes.* FROM Routes
JOIN (SELECT let,dir,min(num) as minnum
      FROM Routes
      GROUP BY let, dir
      ) ld JOIN Routes tt
ON tt.let = ld.let AND tt.dir = ld.dir AND tt.num = ld.minnum 
AND Routes.let = ld.let AND Routes.dir = ld.dir
WHERE tt.ctry = 'CA';
```

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: But why do you want to do that?!?

Comment: Well, yes you could use the old method, but if you know that then not sure why you're asking. Why don't you want to use ANSI join syntax? You're missing join conditions in the `... ld JOIN Routes ...` part, but rewriting in old syntax to 'fix' that would just make a cartesian product. Maybe you're fixing the wrong problem...? Did you mean to only have one Routes, with the tt alias on the first line? You might also want to investigate analytic functions.

Comment: You should add a description of what the code is doing, as well as sample data and desired results.  Also, are you really using Oracle?  The syntax doesn't look valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query properly written:

```
SELECT Routes.*
FROM Routes JOIN
     (SELECT let, dir, min(num) as minnum
      FROM Routes
      GROUP BY let, dir
     ) ld
     ON Routes.let = ld.let AND Routes.dir = ld.dir JOIN
     Routes tt
     ON Routes.let = ld.let AND Routes.dir = ld.dir AND tt.num = ld.minnum 
WHERE tt.ctry = 'CA';
```

You seem to want all routes for a give `let` and `dir` where `num` is minimized.  I don't know what your data looks like, but this looks like a plausible equivalent:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT r.*, MIN(num) OVER (PARTITION BY let, dir) as minnum
      FROM routes r
     ) r.*
WHERE r.ctry = 'CA'; AND num = minnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not like you have any tough joins in here. Pretty much all you need to do is replace the word "JOIN" with a comma, and push all the join conditions down into the WHERE clause. So this is the exact query in traditional Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT Routes.* 
FROM Routes
   ,(SELECT let,dir,min(num) as minnum
      FROM Routes
      GROUP BY let, dir
      ) ld 
   ,Routes tt
WHERE tt.let = ld.let 
  AND tt.dir = ld.dir 
  AND tt.num = ld.minnum 
  AND Routes.let = ld.let 
  AND Routes.dir = ld.dir
  AND tt.ctry = 'CA';
```

That being said, this sure doesn't look like the most efficient way to get this data. I'd skip the third scan of the table and use a partitioned analytic in the same vein as Gordon!